# Buffers Not Overlapping correctly in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, buffer

I have two records in one shapefile that I am trying to create two separate buffers around.

When I go to Geoprocessing - Buffer I choose the desired shapefile, set the desired buffer distance, make the Side Type Full, End Type Round, and Dissolve Type None.

When I run this the first buffer will be an oval as seen in the image, but the second buffer is a weird shape.

How can I make both buffers be an oval?

[image: Buffer not overlapping correctly]

Comment: Have you [checked for geometry errors in the shapefile](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000042000000)?  Strange buffer results are common with incorrect polygon orientation (shapefiles use right hand rule -- clockwise outer rings and counter-clockwise inner rings)

Comment: It's cadastre so a misclose is very likely, this would cause an hourglass polygon or unclosed polygon - both likely to give the same results. I agree with Vince, use Repair Geometry to fix your cadastre before using the buffer tool. End type options only apply to lines, not points or polygons.